# Need a way to check template type and if not in the range of allowed types then have compile time error in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I need to have a template class where each object adds itself to a vector and based on the template type parameter(allowed only: string, int, float) add to the corresponding container. I need a way to have compile time checks for the type and based on the check add to the corresponding container and if the type is not one of the allowed types compile time error should be emitted.
Example: code

```
vector<myClass<int>*> intVec;
vector<myClass<float>*> floatVec;
vector<myClass<string>*> stringVec;

template<typename T>
struct myClass
{
  myClass()
  {
     /*pseudo code
     if(T == int) {
       intVec.push_back(this);
     }
     else if(T == float) {
       floatVec.push_back(this);
     }
     else if(T == string){
       stringVec.push_back(this);
     }
     else {
       // error
     }
     */
  }
  
  T value;
 }
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use specialization and a helper function, e.g.

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct myClass;

inline std::vector<myClass<int>*> intVec;
inline std::vector<myClass<float>*> floatVec;
inline std::vector<myClass<std::string>*> stringVec;

template<typename T>
void add(myClass<T>*);

template<>
void add(myClass<int>* p) {
    intVec.push_back(p);
}

template<>
void add(myClass<float>* p) {
    floatVec.push_back(p);
}

template<>
void add(myClass<std::string>* p) {
    stringVec.push_back(p);
}

template<typename T>
struct myClass
{
    myClass()
    {
        add(this);
    }

    T value;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

In C++17 and later, you can use `if constexpr` and `std::is_same_v`, eg:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct myClass
{
  myClass()
  {
     if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>) {
       m_intVec.push_back(this);
     }
     else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, float>) {
       m_floatVec.push_back(this);
     }
     else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>){
       m_stringVec.push_back(this);
     }
     else {
       // error
     }
  }
  
  T value;
};
```

In earlier versions, you can use either template specialization or SFINAE instead, eg:

```cpp
// via specialization

template<typename T>
struct myClass
{
};

template<>
struct myClass<int>
{
  myClass()
  {
    m_intVec.push_back(this);
  }

  int value;
};

template<>
struct myClass<float>
{
  myClass()
  {
    m_floatVec.push_back(this);
  }

  float value;
};

template<>
struct myClass<std::string>
{
  myClass()
  {
    m_stringVec.push_back(this);
  }

  std::string value;
};
```

```cpp
// via SFINAE

#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct myClass
{
  template<typename U = T, std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, int>::value, int>::type = 0>
  myClass()
  {
    m_intVec.push_back(this);
  }

  template<typename U = T, std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, float>::value, int>::type = 0>
  myClass()
  {
    m_floatVec.push_back(this);
  }

  template<typename U = T, std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, std::string>::value, int>::type = 0>
  myClass()
  {
    m_stringVec.push_back(this);
  }

  T value;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

in addition to existing answers, you can also do it with normal function overloading

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct myClass;

inline std::vector<myClass<int>*> intVec;
inline std::vector<myClass<float>*> floatVec;
inline std::vector<myClass<std::string>*> stringVec;

/* optional
template<typename T>
constexpr bool always_false = false;

template<typename T>
void add(myClass<T>*) {
    static_assert(always_false<T>,"unsupported T");
}
*/

void add(myClass<int>* p) {
    intVec.push_back(p);
}

void add(myClass<float>* p) {
    floatVec.push_back(p);
}

void add(myClass<std::string>* p) {
    stringVec.push_back(p);
}

template<typename T>
struct myClass
{
    myClass()
    {
        add(this);
    }

    T value;
};
```

Comment: Yes! - templates are necessary only when a type can be converted to another type.

Comment: @NarekMeta not sure I got it. template specialization would probably works worse for implicit type conversion than normal overloading.