# How to handle invalid data type being inserted into custom container

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I have a custom Linked List container that I am currently testing.  One of my tests is to first build the container to accept uint8_t types, then attempt to insert a float type and trigger an exception.  The problem is that in my append function, the float gets appended without triggering my exception block.  The actual contents of the node where the float is stored don't show when I print the data, but the size of the Linked list changes after the append, so it does seem the data is getting appended.

How can I check the types in such a way that I force a runtime error to get thrown in this particular case?

Here's my append function code and the test that's failing.

```
...
template <typename T>
        void libdsa::libstructures::LinkedList<T>::append(T datum)
        {
            // Triggers even during a valid insertion.
            // if (typeid(datum) != typeid(this))
            // {
            //    throw std::runtime_error("Invalid type being inserted.");
            // }

            // Fill the head node if it's empty. Otherwise append a new node.
            if (_head == nullptr)
            {
                try
                {
                    _head = new libdsa::libstructures::Node<T>(datum);
                    _head->_next = _head;
                    _head->_prev = _head;
                }
                catch(const std::exception& e)
                {
                    std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    libdsa::libstructures::Node<T> *current = _head;

                    // Create the new node
                    libdsa::libstructures::Node<T> *newNode = new libdsa::libstructures::Node<T>(datum);

                    // Go to the end of the list
                    while (current->_next != _head)
                    {
                        current = current->_next;
                    }

                    // Append the new node and set the directional pointers.
                    current->_next = newNode;
                    newNode->_prev = current;
                    newNode->_next = _head;
                }
                catch(const std::exception& e)
                {
                    std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
                }
            }

            ++_size;
        }
...
```

```
TEST(LinkedList, testInvalidAppend)
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> data = {'C', 'O', 'D', 'E'};
    auto list = setup(data);

    float temp = 23.22;
    list.append(temp);

    list.print();
    ASSERT_EQ(data.size(), list.getSize());
}
```

```
libdsa::libstructures::LinkedList<uint8_t> setup(std::vector<uint8_t> &data)
{
    libdsa::libstructures::LinkedList<uint8_t> list;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
    {
        list.append(data[i]);
    }
    
    return list;
}
```

I'd like an exception (or runtime_error) to be thrown when this invalid action is done, but neither are being triggered at the moment either with or without my conditional statements.

Initially, I attempted to us a try-catch block thinking that the compiler would catch it for me and print out the exception.  However, it did not trigger it and allocated the data block.  The other option I tried was to get the typeids of both the datum being inserted and the type of the container at runtime, but this caused an insertion failure in a successful case (where the type of the data and the container were actually the same).

### Solution Update

Following the first method of PaulMcKenzie's answer, I was able to get it working so the template type T was compared to whatever was passed into the append function by the user, which became template type K.  Below is the new function declaration with my container class and its definition.

```
...
template <typename T>
class LinkedList
{
public:
    /// @brief Default constructor.
    LinkedList() = default;

    /// @brief Appends a new data instance to the end of the list.
    /// @param datum Data instance to be appended.
    template <typename K>
    void append(K datum);
...
```

```
...
template <typename T>
template <typename K>
void libdsa::libstructures::LinkedList<T>::append(K datum)
{         
    if constexpr (!std::is_same_v<T, K>)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid type being appended.");
    }
...
```

This now allows the container to be any data type and for that type to be compared to the type of a data instance the user wants to insert.  After testing his method with the updates, it appears `append()` is now able to force the user to only insert data instances of the same type as the container.  Many thanks to everyone for taking the time to help!

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] to show us. What is `setup` doing? What does it return? What is the use-case of your list, what problem does it solve that any standard container doesn't solve? Also, why should it throw an exception? Why allow different data to begin with? Shouldn't passing the wrong type lead to build-errors instead of run-time exceptions?

Comment: Also note that you should probably not pass `datum` by value.

Comment: Just some side notes. Floats can be converted to ints and vice versa (possibly with loss of precision). Also; I hope you are aware that linked lists are usually a horribly inefficient data structure - why build a custom one? If you really *need* the guarantees a linked list provides, then there's already `std::list` and `std::forward_list` available (use those *if* you really *do* need a linked list), but in most cases what you *really* want is to just use a `std::vector` (use that!).

Comment: [Is this what you are trying to "fix"?](https://godbolt.org/z/MT6aTv9jT).  What you are looking for (probably) is a *compile-time* solution using something like `std::enable_if` or C++ 20 concepts.  You cannot do this at runtime.

Comment: Datum is being taken into the callee by reference so it should have access to the underlying memory.  I'm only implementing the container as a way to gain more experience with C++ features as I'm not familiar with much of the STL.

Comment: @JakobGermann -- This isn't an STL issue -- it is a general template issue.  If you look at the code at the godbolt link I posted, it is the exact same issue you are having, even though the code uses `std::list` instead of your `LinkedList` class.  The `float` has already been converted to a `uint8_t` by the compiler -- it's too late, damage already done.  You have to do a compile-time check to ensure the type being sent is a `uint8_t`.  By doing that, the code will fail to compile if the wrong type is being sent, which is a *good* thing.

Comment: [Does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74647845/need-a-way-to-check-template-type-and-if-not-in-the-range-of-allowed-types-then).

Comment: I believe so.  If I'm understanding the post correctly, they create a new template type (U) and set it equal to T to get the type of the container, and use enable_if to check if it matches any of the specified types.  Is that correct?

Comment: Are you using C++17?  If so, then `if constexpr (!std::is_same_v<T, uint8_t>)` can be used to test for the invalid type at compile time.  If that is satisfactory, I can post this as an answer.

Comment: In addition, `static_assert` using `is_same_v` will give you a compile-time check and will stop the compilation if the type is not `uint8_t`.

Comment: Yes, I'm using C++17.  I will need to play around with this as the condition isn't triggering when float is passed in, but this should be fine for now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the `float` has already been converted to a `uint8_t` at runtime, thus you cannot check this without a compile-time solution.

If you are using C++17 or greater, you can take advantage of `constexpr if`:

```
template <typename T>
void libdsa::libstructures::LinkedList<T>::append(T datum)
{
    if constexpr (!std::is_same_v<T, uint8_t>)
    {
        std::cout << "This is an invalid type " << datum << "\n";
        return;  // or throw an exception
    }
    //...
}
```

If the type is not `uint8_t`, the `if` block is `true` and will execute the code.

Here is a [live example](https://godbolt.org/z/G8h4dKMjd)

---

If you want to stop the compilation and not produce an executable at all if the wrong type is sent, you can use `static_assert` (which works with C++11):

```
#include <cstdint>
//... 
template <typename T>
void libdsa::libstructures::LinkedList<T>::append(T datum)
{
    // This will stop the compilation if the wrong type is sent   
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, uint8_t>, "It is not a uint8_t");
    //...
}
```

Here is a [live example](https://godbolt.org/z/EfhzGE7E5)